# zf-tutorial Fatal Error

Tags: zend-framework

i am starting with zend, with zf-tutorial (the cd app), but i received:

! ) Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Config_Exception' with message 'syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting TC_DOLLAR_CURLY or TC_QUOTED_STRING or '"' in C:\wamp\www\zf-tutorial\library\Zend\Config\Ini.php on line 182
( ! ) Zend_Config_Exception: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting TC_DOLLAR_CURLY or TC_QUOTED_STRING or '"' in C:\wamp\www\zf-tutorial\application/configs/application.ini on line 29 in C:\wamp\www\zf-tutorial\library\Zend\Config\Ini.php on line 182

I checked Ini.php 182:

```
protected function _parseIniFile($filename)
{
    set_error_handler(array($this, '_loadFileErrorHandler'));
    $iniArray = parse_ini_file($filename, true); // Warnings and errors are suppressed
    restore_error_handler();

    // Check if there was a error while loading file
    if ($this->_loadFileErrorStr !== null) {
        /**
         * @see Zend_Config_Exception
         */
        require_once 'Zend/Config/Exception.php';
        throw new Zend_Config_Exception($this->_loadFileErrorStr); <--- THIS ONE No. 182
    }

    return $iniArray;
}
```

But, really, cant figure out the thing.
Thanks in advance. First question i make, and sure, little afraid of having asked some silly

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: 5.3.4 I found about it in http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/application-ini-adaptation-for-php-5-3-td648595.html.. in my case, found syntax errors too...

Answer (score 1):

problem is at

```
application.ini on line 29
```

remove/edit this to test .

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the username and password with a quotation mark.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling the problem may be that your if condition is returning true when it should be false.

Try changing ln. 177 to:

```
if ($this->_loadFileErrorStr !== '') {
```

OR

Try going to your application.ini file and make sure the values that need to be in quotes are quoted:

```
[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
appnamespace = "Application"
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0
phpSettings.date.timezone = "Europe/London"
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/"
resources.view.doctype = "XHTML1_STRICT"

[staging : production]
resources.db.adapter = "pdo_mysql"
resources.db.params.host = "localhost"
resources.db.params.username = "root"
resources.db.params.password = ""
resources.db.params.dbname = "zf-tutoria"
resources.db.params.charset = "utf8"
resources.db.isDefaultTableAdapter = true

[testing : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1

[development : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
```

I discovered this here: http://www.z-f.fr/forum/viewtopic.php?id=6423

Sorry, it's in French, but this ended up being the solution to a similar (the same?) problem.